# Do script readers start at the beginning?

Tags: script, scriptwriting, screenwriting

Script readers-- the people who sift and sort the vast piles of scripts submitted to Hollywood -- do they start at the beginning?

The reason I ask is that I know 99% of scripts are awful and just get thrown out after a couple pages....but if that's true, do they even bother starting at the beginning, or do they just flip to the middle for a sample of the writing?

Comment: Why should they do that? If the beginning is crap, then there is no hope for the middle part. If you are not hooked at the beginning, no-one will read/watch till the middle.

Comment: @JohnSmithers: If it's a movie, you won't walk out after first ten minutes. If the action picks up after the initial exposure, and makes up for the lost time before the end, you will walk out satisfied and recommend the movie to others despite the downer beginning. It's quite frequent that the movie really picks up the pace after halfway through, so it would stand to reason if you want to sift through a bunch of scenarios, a peek at that part would be telling more than the first paragraphs. Now if this is how it works in reality or not...

Comment: @SF. Yes, but there are two things to consider: if you see the same boring beginning on TV, you're going to change channel. In the cinema, you'd be wasting money so you stay. And secondly, watching a movie and reading a script are different things, especially for someone who reads many. I don't know their job, well... But hey, perhaps they occasionally check the middle, who knows. :P

Comment: @Alenanno: People who read scripts don't do this for pleasure of reading but as a job of finding cash-cow superproductions. Their personal feelings don't count nearly as much as their business sense; they don't savour the experience for maximum personal enjoyment, they just perform a job of making selections.

Comment: @SF. Exactly, so if they see a boring beginning they're more likely to trash the whole script, no? I'm not sure I get your point. :)

Comment: @Alenanno: I mean the opposite: They realize a person with cinema ticket won't exit after the first ten minutes, so the beginning is not crucial. If the middle is good enough, the script is worth more attention and the beginning is forgivable.

Comment: @SF. You're talking about established directors/screenwriters, though. You're guaranteed it works. In case of new scripts you need to be able to have a good beginning. I repeat, I'm not one of those, but considering the amount of things they might read, it's not absurd to think they don't give too much chance to a single script (unless the beginning is good).

Comment: It would be very good to wait for an answer from someone with some actual insider knowledge.

Comment: Just curious: Why do you care? Have you written a script that you know starts out awful but gets good in the middle, or vice versa? I wouldn't be surprised if they don't have a fixed rule about such things. If an editor or reviewer starts reading a script and the beginning sucks, I doubt he's going to flip to the middle to see if it gets better: he's going to throw it out. Likewise if he starts in the middle and it sucks, he's not going to go back and check for a good beginning. I suppose a writer could get lucky and the reviewer just happens to flip to the best part ...

Comment: ... Or you could be unlucky and he just happens to start reading the worst part. If he starts at the beginning and it's good but it falls apart in the middle, he's still probably going to reject it. Etc. I don't know how knowledge of the procedure would help anyone. Well, I suppose if you know that he always starts on page 23, you could make sure you have a really good page 23, and maybe win on first impressions.

Comment: I suppose I'm asking because some plots have slower beginnings than others, and I'm wondering if that might be an inherent disadvantage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is, yes, although there's no rule about it, studio readers do seem to start on page one.

Readers looking for scripts for their employers to film look for a lot of things: That there's a basic concept at work in the script, that the three-act structure is being followed... there's [a list](http://myscriptworld.wordpress.com/2007/01/25/studio-readers-checklist/) to be ticked off, and every studio will require their readers look for certain things. But these guys read a *lot* of scripts and only have so much time in the day. It's generally assumed that they may not even finish reading a script, skimming it or even abandoning ones that are not promising.

While [readers not part of a studio](http://gideonsway.wordpress.com/2010/06/19/so-you-want-to-be-a-script-reader/) may read for broad strokes or even just skim the dialog, studio readers seem to just [start at the beginning](http://nofilmschool.com/2012/05/hollywood-script-readers-screenplay/). Saying that you can tell if a script is bad [by the tenth page](http://gointothestory.blcklst.com/2012/05/gits-the-twitter-conversations-script-readers-part-2.html) (and sometimes earlier) seems to be not unusual at all.

There may be some that dip into the middle first; I do this when evaluating manuscripts I may edit, knowing that writers open with a bang and the beginning may be atypical, but if they do, I suspect this isn't the norm. Movies are, by their nature, generally front-loaded, particularly modern ones. So it's never going to hurt to grab the reader up-front, and it's probably expected that you try. Just make sure you follow this through in the rest of your script.

Comment: Caveat: This answer is based on research, reading, and the few conversations I've had over the years with scriptwriters. I have no experience myself as a reader. If we have any studio readers here, I'll gladly defer to their expertise.

Comment: I don't see how this says anything that my answer didn't. This one just uses more words to say the same thing.

Comment: @Kit - Not at all. Your answer was about paid readers/reviewwers, mine's about studio readers. A different anomal altogether.

Comment: anomal?? what is this *anomal*???

Comment: @Aerovistae - *animal

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with screenwriting specifically, but I see no reason why this would be different from the considerations in the fiction market (where "sending chapters" is [**always** the first three chapters](http://www.writersdigest.com/editor-blogs/questions-and-quandaries/which-sample-chapters-should-you-send-to-agents): the reader will start from the beginning, precisely like a viewer would. Why would he do otherwise? That's what makes sense; that's what gives him the best understanding and experience of the work as a whole.

But beginnings are naturally slow and less-exciting? True. Also: tough. Quite simply, **there's no good excuse for having a dull beginning.** As a screenwriter, it's your job to bring the *entire* script up to par - before submission. That means you need to overcome the "how do I draw viewers into the movie" problem, just like later on you'll need to overcome the typical problems of a screenplay's middle and end.

Don't think of it as looking for a "sample of the writing," because that's not really what it is. It's "I'm going to experience this screenplay precisely as a viewer would, but if at any point I'm persuaded that it's not good enough, then I can stop." In a vast majority of cases, that point comes pretty early.

That being said, readers know movies and their genres. You don't need to start out with an erupting volcano because the opening of your domestic dramady isn't exciting enough. Lots of movies open with endearing characters, or great settings, or fun dialogue, or whatever. If you know why **you** would be riveted to this movie from the start, why your expected audience would leap right into this movie as soon as it begins, then you're absolutely fine. But if *everybody* would be bored by the first 15 minutes before "things get interesting," then that's a real problem - and the reader's quite right to reject your script as unready.

Answer (score 0):

### Analysts Read from the beginning (the Title) to the end without any sneak peaks ahead. They don't want to accidentally read any spoilers.

The book "Writing Scripts Hollywood Will Love [An Insider's Guide to Film and Television Scripts That Sell]" is by Katherine Atwell Herbert, an actual professional script analyst; she was the first reader for *Robocop* and *Bill and Ted's Excellent Adventure*.

The third chapter of that book details how script analysts work, and YES, they read from the beginning to the end; take notes along the way for themselves, and so on.

They may take overall impressions just from the title, page count, formatting and "density" on the page, but they do not ***read*** in the middle because they don't want to see any reveals or spoilers: They want to judge tension and open questions as they go, to simulate the experience of a seen movie.

On titles: *Chris Meindl, reader for MGM:*

> "Titles are sometimes an indication that the writer has given this project more than a moment's thought. Good titles will have resonance or call up associations. Too many scripts have two word titles that sum up a high concept story and we already know how the story works before we even read it."

She says nearly all readers look at the length; if it is not between 100 and 130 pages, the reader suspects the writer's professionalism, and assume "the writer does not know how to tell a story in the context of a film".

The script analyst will also notice (and become biased by) any typos, non-standard fonts being used, missing punctuation, horrific grammar. All are unprofessional.

Most script analysts have made much of their judgment within a FEW pages:

> For a six year veteran at a major studio the most common script problem is, "predictable people relying on clichéd events." In these scripts, "you know what's going to happen in the story after only a couple of pages," she adds. She hardly needs to read further, but of course, she does.
>
> For some analysts the first few pages of a script are indicative of its overall merit. Meindl has found that, "You know in the first few pages if you're in the hands of a capable writer."
>
> A senior VP of production at Twentieth-Century Fox is concerned with neatness, spelling and grammar and is also put off by scripts that, "are too dense. There's not enough white space on the page." Or as Allen Page, an analyst at Warner Brothers who has also taught various film courses, remarked, "a script should be easy on the eye. It should be script-like rather than novelistic." Being too dense means there is too much description, which means the writer is probably overwriting.

The book is worth buying if you are serious about script writing. Later in Ch3 she says:

> Nonetheless, the readers stick with it to the end, and turns each page hoping to find originality, something unusual that will spark their interest, or a creative approach to the plot development, the hero's problem, the description of characters and the theme. Most of the time they don't find it.